# Confusion with setId() method in Android

Tags: android, view

This is the description given for the `setId()` method.

> ```
> void  android.view.View.setId(int id)
> ```
>
> public void setId (int id)
>
> Since: API Level 1
>
> Sets the identifier for this view. The identifier does not have to be
>   unique in this view's hierarchy. The identifier should be a positive
>   number.

My question is, why does the identifier not have to be unique in this view's hierarchy though we assign unique ids in an XML file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My question is, why does the identifier not have to be unique in this view's hierarchy though we assign unigue id in xml file..?

The `android:id` does not have to be unique in the XML file, either, though that is the way you write it, typically.

To understand why a widget ID does not need to be unique, consider the `ListView`. Let's say that we have a `ListView` with 8 rows. Each of those rows is created by inflating a layout XML resource (e.g., `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`). Each of those inflated rows are children of the `ListView`. Yet, since each of those rows is inflated from the same layout resource, each row's widgets have the same IDs as all the other rows.

This is not generally a problem. It does lead to one cardinal rule of Android development: **always call `findViewById()` on something that will give you a unique result for the widget you seek**. In this case, I do not want to call `findViewById()` on the `ListView` or the `Activity` to find a widget inside of one of the rows, as there will be 8 widgets all with the same ID, and I do not know which row's widget I will get back. Instead, I need to call `findViewById()` on the *row*, to get the particular widget from that specific row.

Answer (score 2):

IDs need not to be unique, you can use any positive integer you like, but in this case there can be some views with equivalent id's.

Also Like Romain Guy Said in [this](https://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/91efb49a87a9a4bd#) post:

`findViewById()` is a **depth-first** search algorithm; it will return the first view of the specified id it can find.